# Where to find or override _navbar.scss?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I'm using this template here https://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/resume/. I'd like to change the hover/active effect of the navigation links, but I cannot figure how to override it or where it's being rendered or controlled from. [Google inspect leads me to _navbar.scss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTVK8.png) It shows the hover/focus being controlled by

```
.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover
```

I've tried changing and overriding the CSS in a number of places and I've tried making my own _navbar.css and my own classes but it doesn't work. I'd really appreciate if anyone could point me to the correct location and also how you found it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The theme's documentation should help you:
https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-resume

Make your changes to _navbar.scss, and then run `gulp sass` to concatenate and convert your SCSS to CSS.

Comment: _nabar.scss doesn't exist anywhere. Am I supposed to create it then run gulp?

Comment: Follow the getting started instructions in the documentation, it should get created.

Answer (score 1):

You can override _navbar.scss by just referencing a class name in your css file.  For example:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Will override the bootstrap generated class to have 10 pixels of padding at the top.

Comment: Just copied the modified css from bootstrap.css to site.css. This worked for me.